# On select item in RecyclerView get unique key from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I would like to know how to get Key from Firebase when selected Item at custom RecyclerView. Here is my scenario.

- MainActivity(contain fragment) is displaying custom RecyclerView(1 Image +3 text).
- Upon click on one item, display the detail in an activity(in Editable mode: Means user want to edit or delete this item). I read data at a position and sent through a bundle.
- Problem is I don't know how to get the uniqueKey of that line item, because of I need it for the update back to firebase database, or delete it upon user decision.

**Firebase Image Here**:

[image]

my Code as following:

```
    package com.abc.personalexpensestracker;

   import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
    import io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.SectionParameters;
    import io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter;
    import io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter.StatelessSection;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class CurrentmonthFragment extends Fragment {

        private SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter mSectionAdapter; 

        private FloatingActionButton mCurrMonthAddFab;

        private RecyclerView mTransactionsList;
        private DatabaseReference mUsersTransactionsDatabase;

        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseUser mCurrUser;

        private ArrayList<TransactionsData transactionsListViewValuesArr =null;

        private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;


        public CurrentmonthFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();


            mTransactionsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            //mTransactionsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mSectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(); 

            //// Set data in arraylist
            transactionsListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<TransactionsData();
            setTransactionsListData();

            mUsersTransactionsDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    //check if there are categories with current user ID
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                        LinkedHashSet<String uniqueSetDate = new LinkedHashSet<String();

                        //first get unique Date from database
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            uniqueSetDate.add(data.child("datetime").getValue().toString());

                        }

                        //Bind recyclerView by Section, group by date
                        for(String sDate : uniqueSetDate) {
                            String sDatetime =sDate;
                            ArrayList<TransactionsData transactionsPerDay = getTransactionsPerDay(sDate, transactionsListViewValuesArr);
                            if (transactionsPerDay.size()  0) {
                                mSectionAdapter.addSection(new TransactionsSection(String.valueOf(sDatetime), transactionsPerDay));
                            }
                            mTransactionsList.setAdapter(mSectionAdapter);
                        }

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currentmonth, container, false);


            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mCurrUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            mUsersTransactionsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users_transactions").child(mCurrUser.getUid()).child("by_year").child(String.valueOf(mYear)).child(String.valueOf(mMonth));


            mCurrMonthAddFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.current_month_add_fab);
            mCurrMonthAddFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent newTransactionIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),AddNewTransaction.class);
                    startActivity(newTransactionIntent);

                }
            });


            mTransactionsList= (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.ListView_Curr_Transactions);


            return view;

        }


        public static class TransactionsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            View mView;

            public TransactionsViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                mView = itemView;
            }

            public  void setTransactCat(String name){
                TextView categoryName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_TransSingle_CatName);
                categoryName.setText(name);
            }

            public void setTransactCatImage(String image, Context ctx){
                CircleImageView catImageView= (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.img_TransSingle_Cat);
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).placeholder(R.mipmap.question_circular_button).into(catImageView);

            }
            public  void setTransactDate(String transactDate){
                TextView categoryName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_TransSingle_Date);
                categoryName.setText(transactDate);
            }

            public  void setTransactAmount(Double transactAmount){
                TextView categoryName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_TransSingle_Amt);
                if (!Double.isNaN(transactAmount)){
                    categoryName.setText(transactAmount.toString());
                }
            }

        }


        private ArrayList<TransactionsData getTransactionsPerDay(String date, ArrayList<TransactionsData transactionsList) {
            ArrayList<TransactionsData transactions = new ArrayList<TransactionsData();

            for(int i = 0; i < transactionsList.size(); i++) {
                //System.out.println(transactionsListViewValuesArr.get(i)); //prints element i
                TransactionsData transaction = transactionsList.get(i);
                if (transaction.getDatetime().equals(date)) {
                    transactions.add(transaction);
                }
            }

            return transactions;
        }



        private class TransactionsSection extends StatelessSection {

            String title;
            ArrayList<TransactionsData alist;

            TransactionsSection(String title, ArrayList<TransactionsData list) {
                super(new SectionParameters.Builder(R.layout.transactions_single_layout)
                        .headerResourceId(R.layout.transactions_section_header)
                        .build());

                this.title = title;
                this.alist = list;
            }

            @Override
            public int getContentItemsTotal() {
                return alist.size();
            }

            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
                return new TransactionsViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                final TransactionsViewHolder itemHolder = (TransactionsViewHolder) holder;


                final TransactionsData tData = alist.get(position);

                itemHolder.setTransactDate(tData.getDatetime());
                itemHolder.setTransactCat(tData.getCategory());
                itemHolder.setTransactAmount(tData.getAmount());


                itemHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.format("Clicked on position #%s of Section %s", mSectionAdapter.getPositionInSection(itemHolder.getAdapterPosition()), title), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent editTransactionIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),EditExistingTransaction.class);
                        Bundle transactionBundle = new Bundle();
                        transactionBundle.putDouble("selected_amount",tData.getAmount());
                        transactionBundle.putString("selected_catType",tData.getCategory_type());
                        transactionBundle.putString("selected_catName",tData.getCategory());
                        transactionBundle.putString("selected_date",tData.getDatetime());
                        transactionBundle.putString("selected_note",tData.getNotes());
                        editTransactionIntent.putExtras(transactionBundle);
                        startActivity(editTransactionIntent);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
                return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
                HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;

                headerHolder.tvTitle.setText(title);
            }
        }


        private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private final TextView tvTitle;

            HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_transaction_header_date);
            }
        }


        /****** Function to set data in ArrayList *************/
        public void setTransactionsListData()
        {

            //transactionsListViewValuesArr.add(new TransactionsData(5.5,"default","default","default","default"));

            mUsersTransactionsDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot categorySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String transactionCat = categorySnapshot.child("category").getValue(String.class);
                        String transactionDate = categorySnapshot.child("datetime").getValue(String.class);
                        Double transactionAmt = categorySnapshot.child("amount").getValue(Double.class);
                        String transactionCatType = categorySnapshot.child("category_type").getValue(String.class);
                        String transactionNote = categorySnapshot.child("notes").getValue(String.class);

                        final TransactionsData transactionsData = new TransactionsData();
                        /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
                        transactionsData.setCategory(transactionCat);
                        transactionsData.setDatetime(transactionDate);
                        transactionsData.setAmount(transactionAmt);
                        transactionsData.setCategory_type(transactionCatType);
                        transactionsData.setNotes(transactionNote);


                        /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
                        transactionsListViewValuesArr.add(transactionsData);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the code for storing all key in an ArrayList from the dataSnapshot

```
HashMap<String, Object> allData = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
String[] allKey = allData.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

You can also get key while loop is running

```
for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String key = data.getKey();

                    }
```

Comment: So, if I go with second option, that means I need to have a hidden textview(in each item in recyclerView layout) to store that key. Then retrieve from the textview at onClickListener?  (sorry if this likes dumb question. this is my first Android app and never code in Java before)

Comment: no .. you dont need to have a hidden textview in order to get the key value. just store the value wherever u want .

Comment: Thank you @Shahadat Hossain Shaki. I use the second option and added getter/setter to store the key together with data.

Comment: Welcome.. U have to use getter and setter for storing the value in same class.. :)